# Element focus listener not triggered after first element.focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I've noticed a rather odd behavior when running a unit test which passed on PhantomJS but occasionally failed in Chrome, Firefox and IE. In a nutshell:

- I set a focus listener for a DOM element.
- I invoked `element.focus()`, yet the listener was not run.
- Calling `element.focus()` for a second time actually ran the listener.

Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this issue in a fiddle, but it can be done, for instance, in jQuery's website. I do the following steps on Chrome:

1. Open www.jquery.com and then open DevTools.
2. Run `$("input[name=s]").on("focus", () => console.log("a"));`.
3. Run `$("input[name=s]").focus();`. No output is generated.
4. Run `$("input[name=s]").focus();`. Now "a" is printed to the console for the first time!

What is causing this issue and how could I work around it?

Answer (score 2):

Had a quick delve around the jquery source code, and it seems that focus actually uses focusin, and the code is trying to map to focusin. so if you try this:

> $("input[name=s]").on("focusin", () => console.log("a"));
>
> $("input[name=s]").focusin();

it will work. There is a difference between focus and focusin around bubbling:

http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside
> of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it
> supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words,
> it supports event bubbling).

It seems like the behaviour is a hard to replicate bug, that must be caused by other bit of code somewhere (maybe a lib). Although the code above should help work around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've changed the failing unit tests and the associated code to use focusin rather than focus. I also found some issues with blur, but changing it to focusout worked well too. :) I'll still need to look further into the issue and see what was causing it in the first place.